# CSS with tables, empty rows without border

Tags: vaadin, border, css

I use Vaadin in my project, currently i'm having a problem with it. It's CSS/HTML problem and i'm not aware how can i fix it...

So the situation looks like that:

I've got HTML structure (CustomLayout) which looks like that:

```
<table> 
<tr>
    <td location="loc11"></td>
    <td location="loc12"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td location="loc21"></td>
    <td location="loc22"></td>
</tr>
(...) 
</table>
```

I'm inserting data into td with location="xxx", the data is in some locations not everyone. CSS looks like that:

```
table.metric_table_layout tr td {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted grey !important;
}
```

And here's the problem:

[image: the dots...]

If the td is empty, i have borders that completly ruined my layout.
Could someone give me some CSS (that will works also in IE 7+) to fix this ? 
I don't want to use JS, so i'm not sure if i can handle this with only CSS?

Thx 
tzim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add:

```
table.metric_table_layout {
    border-collapse:separate;
    empty-cells:hide;
}
```

But in IE8 there has to be a `!DOCTYPE` definition.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS only you can use the `empty-cells:hide` property. It's buggy across browsers so do some previews in all (rendered ok in my IE7 from IEtester - I just had to define the border as #ccc instead of gray)

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/EbvXQ/11/